# Unity Editor - C#: Why does my list reset to null OnEnable?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a custom unity editor and for some reason every time I close the window and open it again, my list resets to null.

I'm trying to save data from a dictionary by separating the keys and values into 2 separate lists `OnDisable`, and then re-creating the dictionary `OnEnable` by combining the lists. But every time `OnEnable` is called I get a null from my lists...

Here's an example of what the code looks like.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

[SerializeField]
public List<string> listOfDictionaryKeys;


    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // this always returns null
        Debug.Log(listOfDictionaryKeys.Count);

    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        // this successfully saves the keys to the list
        listOfDictionaryKeys = (myDictionary.Keys).ToList();

    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas why I could be losing my list data? I'm not setting any values in an inspector, they're all being set and saved by code.

Comment: Best is you always initialize lists like `public List<string> listOfDictionaryKeys = new List<string>();` is this the whole code because I don't see where in `OnEnable` you recreate the list...

Comment: @derHugo I populate the list in `onDisable` and in `OnEnable` I try to get a count from it to see if it's null and it always returned null.

I changed `public List<string> listOfDictionaryKeys;` to `public static List<string> listOfDictionaryKeys = new List<string>();` and now when i close and open the window the list works as it should, however, whenever the script recompiles I lose the list data again

Comment: I don't understand why you are populating it only in `OnDisable`?

Comment: @derHugo because the list is just a way of trying to save my dictionary entries, after `OnDisable` my dictionary gets wiped to null, so I'm trying to save whatever data I have in my dictionary into 2 lists `OnDisable` (on list of keys and one list of values) and then reload that same data from the 2 lists back into the dictionary in `OnEnable`. But my lists' data is being wiped out as well and I can't figure out why

Comment: Your question is not really clear. I have a guess what happens but would have to see exactly how your setup is for the class and the editor script for it. Also it would help a lot to actually see how and where exactly you fill that list. Also where are you filling the dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

UnityEditor is a (great tool) tricky beast, that runs its own callback loop, and serialisation and deserialisation within the editor can be a bit messy.

Sometimes unity will igoner whatever constructor of an object did, and override it with default values, on the next update. I imagine that the inspector of an object initializes it when it finds null where a list is expected, but if you don't save the new serialized form with your scene, it will remain null, and will be null when OnEnable happens in the bulld (after deserialisation), unless its saved with the scene.

I do not have a full grasp of the process but that's how I imagine it.

For a quick workaround do:

```
private void OnEnable()
{
    if (listOfDictionaryKeys==null) listOfDictionaryKeys=new List<string>();
    // this always returns null
    Debug.Log(listOfDictionaryKeys.Count);

}
```

this way you won't accidentally erase it in case it exists

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand from your question whether `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` are part of your editor script or the component itself.

If the later:

`OnEnable` is called when the component goes from disabled to enabled state, **not** when it gains focus in the inspector. The same way `OnDisabled` is called when the component or according GameObject is disabled, **not** if it loses focus.

If what you want is reacting to gaining and loosing focus in the inspector it would have to be `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` of the Inspector script itself. E.g.

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(XY)]
public class XYEditor : Editor
{
    XY _target;
    SerializedProperty list;

    // Called when the class gains focus
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _target = (XY) target;

        //Link the SerializedProperty
        list = serializedObject.FindProperty("listOfDictionaryKeys");
    }

    public override void OnInpectorGUI()
    {
        //whatever your inspector does
    }

    // Called when the component looses focus
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        serializedObjet.Update();

        // empty list
        list.ClearArray;

        // Reading access to the target's fields is okey 
        // as long as you are sure they are set at the moment the editor is closed
        foreach(var key in _target.myDoctionary.keys)
        {
            list.AddArrayElementAtIndex(list.arraySize);
            var element = list.GetArrayElementAtIndex(list.arraySize - 1);
            element.stringValue = key;
        }

        serialzedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties;
    }
}
```

I also don't see where you populate the dictionary since you say it is not happening in the inspector. This might be a problem when mixonb`SerializedProperty` with direct access to fields.

Comment: The code in the post is part of the editor script. The dictionary is populated in the same script via entry into custom editor windows. I put the functionality in `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` because those are the first and last methods to be called when the inspector window is closed/opened. Right now when I close my custom editor window and re-open it everything works as it should, the dictionary is copied into 2 lists when `OnDisable` is called and then those 2 lists repopulate the dictionary in `OnEnable`. But when my editor script recompiles, I once again lose the data and get null lists